# Count Data from multiple tables

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, grouping

I have 3 tables T1,T2,T3.
Each of them has a relation to another.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
SELECT     T1.T1_Serno, T2.T2_Serno, T3.T3_Serno, T1.T1,COUNT( T3.T3_Serno) as Count_1, T2.T2, T3.T3, T3.Quantity
FROM         T1 INNER JOIN
                      T2 ON T1.T1_Serno = T2.T1_Serno INNER JOIN
                      T3 ON T2.T2_Serno = T3.T2_Serno
GROUP BY T1.T1_Serno, T2.T2_Serno, T3.T3_Serno, T1.T1, T2.T2, T3.T3, T3.Quantity
```

and the result is

[image]

I am looking to get the Count_1 to show me how many T3 are there and Count_2 to have the relative Count of Quantity of T3.
I am expecting a result like

```
   T2    T3      Count_1 Count_2
    Apple Apple1    3    80
    Apple Apple2    3    80
    Apple Apple3    3    80
    -------
    Google Google1  1    40
    ------
    Nokia Nokia1    1    15
```

So that when I put this in a grid I can use the Counts as Footer.
Something like this but with the totals beneath each Group.

[image]

Comment: I can not understand what do you want to do? are you referring sum(Quantity) as Count_2? may you please explain more precisely

Comment: I have just updated the question Sir.

Comment: Thanks, what about adding this piece of code to your select... COUNT( T2.T2_Serno) as COUNT_2 ... Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
SELECT t2.t2,t3.t3,sum(t3.Quantity)
FROM T2 AS T2
INNER JOIN T3 AS T3 ON t3.t2_serno = t2.t2_serno
GROUP BY t2.t2,t3.t3
```

In essence, you wanted to group things by 1 primary grouping (t2) and 1 secondary grouping (t3). So when you do a sql server `group by`, it creates grouping within groupings (if you have multiple grouping elements). The leftmost grouping element will be the primary grouping and reading from left to right will be the sub groupings. That's how I got `GROUP By t2.t2,t3.t3`.

Once I understood how you wanted it grouped, I looked at the column quantity. You wanted the sum of the quantity column in t3. Since t3.t3 is a sub group of t2.t2, sql server applied the column aggregate to all rows by the t3.t3 sub group, which is already grouped by the t2.t2 grouping.

**TL;DR**:
The group by clause in sql server has precendent from left to right, creating groupings with in groupings. If you apply an aggregate to a column within a sub group, the aggregate will magically (very logically if you understand the sql engine) work for every item in the  sub group and start over at each new sub group instance.

Comment: Can you explain ? (Flagged as a low quality post by SO)

Comment: @rico updated with an explanation, let me know if the explanation is not understandable or plain wrong.

Comment: @rene updated with an explanation, let me know if the explanation is not understandable or plain wrong.

Comment: I don't come across a lot of users that improve their answer like you did. Great!

Comment: thank you all for your participation but I am looking to group this in a gridview.. Something like Group the T3 and Quantity with T2 as the header.Something like : Apple 80- >Apple1 -20 Apple2 50 Apple3 10 ... etc So Apple  -80 (T2) will he the category and the subcategory will be the T3